# All sub links have /home/ in the url for wordpress install

Tags: wordpress

Basically any of my pages outside of the home page all have home in the url. Something like domain.com/home/about instead of just domain.com/about.

If I go to edit the page, I can change the about part, but the domain.com/home/ is not editable. Where could I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value of Site Address(URL) from administration panel:-

1. Settings -> General

and remove "home/" if it is there. Update me if you still have the same issue.

Comment: I had already checked that, it is literally set to http://www.example.com

There is no home there. I should note this is a godaddy managed wordpress install that I didn't build. I'm just trying to figure this out for a client who set it up themselves.